# The Minkowski functional p is positively homogeneous

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

Defining the Minkowski functional $p(x)= \inf {\{r>0:r^{−1}x∈S}\}$ for $S$ being a convex body having $0$ as an interior point, the book uses the following to prove if it is homogeneous : $$p(ax) = \inf {\{r>0:ar^{−1}x∈S}\} = \inf {\{ar>0:r^{−1}x∈S}\} = a \inf {\{r>0:r^{−1}x∈S}\} = ap(x).$$ How $\inf {\{r>0:ar^{−1}x∈S}\} = \inf {\{ar>0:r^{−1}x∈S}\}$ holds?

Answer (score 1):

The result is immediate for $a = 0$. So, suppose $a>0$.

Then, we have
\begin{align*}  
\inf \{ r>0 : a r^{-1}x \in S \} &=\inf \{ a(a^{-1} r)>0 : (a^{-1} r)^{-1}x \in S \} =\\
&= \inf \{ a t>0 : t^{-1}x \in S \} =\\
&= \inf \{ a r>0 : r^{-1}x \in S \} 
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot :)